# Entity Framework not performing code-first and throwing DbUpdateException due to missing table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This is the model I want to add to my database:

```
[Table("Posts")]
public class PostEntity
{
    [Key]
    [Column("PostId")]
    public Guid PostId { get; set; }

    [Column("PostContent")]
    public string PostContent { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [Column("User")]
    public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
}
```

and this is the code to do this:

```
var postEntity = new PostEntity()
{
    PostContent = model.PostContent,
    PostId = Guid.NewGuid(),
    UserId = user.Id
};

try
{
    m_accountDbContext.PostDbCtx.Add(postEntity);
    await m_accountDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
catch(ModelValidationException e )
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
catch(InvalidOperationException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}
catch(DbUpdateException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
}

return true;
```

The database does not have the table `Posts` at the moment. So far, whenever I used to work with EF, code-first took care of dealing with the creation of the database.

However, in this case, when I run the code, a `DbUpdateException` is thrown, with an error inside which goes like

> Invalid object : dbo.Posts

Therefore I conclude that it is unable to find the table. However, I expect it to build it up for me.

Is there something I missed?

Comment: Automatic Migrations might not be enabled for you. Here is a [MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554735(v=vs.113).aspx#Enabling%20Migrations) on how to set this up.

Comment: Either enable automatic migration and run `Update-Database` command or do the migration with `Add-Migration -Name add-post-table` then `Update-Database` command.

Comment: @bman7716 That worked perfectly, thanks! I am still wondering why it failed in first place, though. I never had to use code migration